# How to set many url schemes in Info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios, url, url-scheme, info-plist

I want to set more than one url schemes in Info.pist. But I don't Know how to set many url schemes  in Info.plsit. Who can help me, I'm a fish

Comment: Please ask question more clearly. Do you want to add more row (key)?  In info.plist when you hover mouse on a particular row you will get + sign. Click it and a new row will be added.Then you can add new key. or you asking for something else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Project Navigator->*YourInfo*.plist click on it;
than click "+" under selected line in picture sample, and you'll get new item for other url scheme.

[image: new url scheme]

here we have two schemes:

one://

two://

**EDIT1: as text :**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>one</string>
            <string>two</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

CFBundleURLTypes
    
        
            CFBundleTypeRole
            
            CFBundleURLSchemes
            
                third
            
        
        
            CFBundleTypeRole
            Editor
            CFBundleURLSchemes
            
                one
                two

**EDIT2:just as text with third option as different:**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>three</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>one</string>
            <string>two</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: But I want two different "CFBundleTypeRole" , How to do.

Answer (score 0):

just click the `+` on any of the row & try to type URL that will show you URL SCHEME as the array.